# Rails: checksum of uploaded files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, file-upload, checksum, sha256

I am generating the checksum (sha256) of an uploaded image in Ruby on Rails.

```
upload = params[:file]
data1 = upload.read
data2 = File.read(upload.tempfile)
checksum1 = Digest::SHA256.hexdigest(data1)
checksum2 = Digest::SHA256.hexdigest(data2)
puts checksum1
puts checksum2
```

Last two statements are returning different values. 
checksum1 is generated by reading the data using the UploadedFile object.
checksum2 is generated by reading the temporary file from the file system.

Does an object of ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile return anything more than the contents of the uploaded file? When I generate the checksum of the uploaded file written to the file-system, it is matching with `checksum2` (temporary file checksum) , not with `checksum1` (UploadedFile.read).

I am assuming that the checksum generated by reading the temporary file from the filesystem is more reliable as the object (UploadedFile) implementation might change. If needed, it will be easier to generate checksums of existing files on the file system.

So, what is the reason for the difference of checksums and which one is more reliable?

Thank you.

---

Update 1:
As per @pablo-castellazzi suggestion i generated the hash by using Digest::SHA256.file(upload.path).hexdigest . Let us call this checksum3

This checksum3 equals checksum1 but differs from checksum2

---

Update 2: If i use the binary mode to read the file as mentioned by @Arsen7 , then all the checksums are equal.

Comment: For future reference, a better way to get a file checksum is `Digest::SHA256.file(path_to_file).hexdigest`. Using File.read may lead to an out of memory error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you compared the 'data1' and 'data2' contents? Try to save them to files and take a look.

I suppose, you may want to call **`upload.rewind`** before you do the first read, but the first thing is to take a look at the raw data read from the files.

**Update:**

You did not say that you are on Windows. In this case you should take care and read the files in so-called 'binary' mode.

Change the `File.read` method to something like this:

```
data2 = nil
File.open(upload.path, "rb") {|f| data2 = f.read }
```

(Implement Pablo Castellazzi suggestion of using `.path` method)

I was suggesting that you open the files in some binary-safe editor (vim, for example) and compare what differs. You would notice that maybe most of the data is the same, but in one of the files line endings are different, or maybe you would spot some other differences.

In case of Windows, the most popular problem is the binary mode.

Comment: When i write the data1 and data2 to the disk, data1 shows up as a proper image, data2 gets distorted.

Comment: Thank you sir, binary mode it was. :) 
Can i use the 'rb' mode on non-windows machines?

Comment: Yes, you can. On other systems it is silently ignored. And don't call me "sir". I am too humble for this title ;-))

Comment: this also worked with me - a cross platform ruby app - linux and windows. windows was different until i used this

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using Rails 3.x data1 checksum is correct. data2 content should be read with:

```
data2 = File.read(upload.path)
```

upload.tempfile is the instance holding the file object, not the path to the temporary file.

[Here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Http/UploadedFile.html) are the relevant implementation details.

Also this is weird, because File.read(File.read) should throw some kind of exception about a file not found or an invalid file name.

Comment: tempfile contains the path to the temporary file. Here is the data from the logs: [sorry for the non-existent formatting]
Parameters: "file"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x1c0c638 @original_filename="lorry.jpg", 
@content_type="image/jpeg", 
@headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\";filename=\"lorry.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n", 
@tempfile=#<File:C:/DOCUME~1/User1/LOCALS~1/Temp/RackMultipart20110621-2496-1lnrcpi>>}

Comment: Not really. As you may see from the representation @tempfile is a File instance pointing to "C:/DOCUME~1/User1/LOCALS~1/Temp/RackMultipart20110621-2496-1lnrcpi". A path is just a string, its representation should be something like @tempfile="C:/DOCUME~1/User1/LOCALS~1/Temp/RackMultipart20110621-2496-1lnrcpi"

Comment: You are right. I have used 'path' and it is working as expected. Probably the to_s method on the object of File returns the path...